# Passing multiple variables between pages and using them

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three variables I'm trying to pass from one page to another: Two checboxlists (just the checked values) and one DateTime.

I'm getting the checked items like this (this is just for one of these checkboxlists which is called lstUsers):

```
    string cblvalues = "";

    foreach (ListItem cbitem in lstUsers.Items)
    {
        if (cbitem.Selected)
        {
            cblvalues += cbitem.Value + "-";
        }
    }
    cblvalues = cblvalues.Trim('-');
    Response.Redirect("Results.aspx?cblvalues=" + cblvalues);
```

How would I pass the other checkboxlist and the DateTime to "Results.aspx" as well? I've seen a few different examples such as Server.Transfer, and I'm not sure which one is correct here.

And for using them on the Results.aspx page, would I just do:

```
string cblvalues = Request.QueryString["cblvalues"];
```

Comment: Are you trying to make them all query strings within the href?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put as many values as you like on the query string.  (Though as query strings get *very long* the web server would eventually impose a limit.)  Here you simply append one key/value pair:

```
Response.Redirect("Results.aspx?cblvalues=" + cblvalues);
```

Just use a `&` to separate additional key/value pairs:

```
Response.Redirect("Results.aspx?cblvalues=" + cblvalues + "&moreValue=" + moreValues);
```

---

If you do get to the point where the query string becomes absurdly long and you basically have *a lot* of data to pass to the next page, then you'd be looking at other ways of doing this.  A simple alternative may be to store the values in session state, redirect the user, then pull the values from session state.  Something as simple as this:

```
Session["cblvalues"] = cblvalues;
Session["moreValues"] = moreValues;
Response.Redirect("Results.aspx");
```

Then in `Results.aspx` you can get the values:

```
var cblValues = Session["cblvalues"];
// etc.
```

You might also clear the session values once you get them, if the session doesn't need to keep carrying them:

```
Session.Remove("cblvalues");
```

Comment: Is there a difference between doing it this way and the String.Format way that D Mayuri answered?

Comment: @pfinferno: Not really, this just uses the string building method you were already using.  The resulting string would be no different, though `strinig.Format()` is often preferred for constructing strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass multiple values through query string by seperated them with a `&`
so your snippet will be like the following:
Let `cblSecond` be the second `combobox` then;

```
// Building first value here
foreach (ListItem cbitem in cblSecond.Items)
    {
        if (cbitem.Selected)
        {
            cblSecondValues += cbitem.Value + "-";
        }
    } 
Response.Redirect("Results.aspx?cblvalues=" + cblvalues + "&cblSecondValues=" + cblSecondValues);
```

So that you can access them separately like this:

```
 string cblvalues = Request.QueryString["cblvalues"];// gives you the first value
 string cblSecondValues= Request.QueryString["cblSecondValues"];// gives you the second value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("Results.aspx?value1={0}&value2={1}&value3={2}", Value1, Value2, Value3));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to pass them using querystring then you ahouls include them as well

```
Response.Redirect("Results.aspx?cblvalues=" + cblvalues + "&cblvalues1=" + cblvalues + "&datetimemy=" + datetimevalue);
```

Form of a query string like below

```
http://server_name/path/aspxfile?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3..&fieldn=valuen
```

As other answer mentioned, there are multiple ways like using `Session` or `cookies` or as well you can expose those control values as public properties and use then in next page using `Page.PreviousPage` property but the restriction is that you will have to use either of `Server.Transfer()` or `Server.Execute()` method instead of `Response.Redirect`.